# How do I make use of UID to find obtain user details?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

In my database, there are `posts` (Post details) and `users` (User Information). How can I make use of the `UID` from Posts to find the username from `Users` (as `UID` is present in both)?

Is there a way to get `UID` (the only method i kept coming across is get current uid, which I dont have because I want the `UID` of the person who created the post), match it in `users` and get username from there?

Any form of help will be appreciated as I am stuck at this for days.

```
{
  "posts" : {
    "65smvSYkhfVBtM2GrPmOl3cdgDy1" : {
        "image" : "",
        "Title" : "Testing",
        "Description" : "Apples are red",
        "UID" : "FOCSwhfIZSOpqUgueoWlakSkVYr1",        
      }
    },
{
   "users" : {
    "FOCSwhfIZSOpqUgueoWlakSkVYr1" : {
        "Name" : "Curie ",
        "mobileNumber" : "80690 00343",
        "specialization" : "Philosopher"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following are the steps that I would take:

1. It seems like you're going to need to get the value that is in the
   **UID** field from the individual post that you're interested in.
2. From there, you'll then want to do a lookup against the Users table
   using the data you got from the UID field in the post. Here, you'll compare the UID from step 1 to the actual `users/$uid`.

If step 2 is difficult, then think about it this way. You need to do a comparison of the **UID** field data that you got from the `posts` table versus each potential user in the `users` table. If you needed to do this manually, then you'd likely need to generate a list of the users and then do a loop through each user and compare the data until you find a UID match.

Luckily, the data is already indexed and therefore the lookup time for the UID in the `users` table will be fast (dictionary lookup times).